# C# Regex split by multiple closing brackets sets

Tags: c#, regex

This is the source:

```
( ( ERDAT > '20210224' ) OR ( ERDAT = '20210224' AND ERFZEIT > '085956' ) OR ( AEDAT > '20210224' ) OR ( AEDAT = '20210224' AND AEZEIT > '231217' ) ) AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM10', 'PM99' ) )
```

Using this regex : `(?<=\))\s`

I get this:

```
( ( ERDAT > '20210224' )
OR ( ERDAT = '20210224' AND ERFZEIT > '085956' )
OR ( AEDAT > '20210224' )
OR ( AEDAT = '20210224' AND AEZEIT > '231217' )
)
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM10', 'PM99' )
)
```

Note the single closing brackets on their own line. What I would like is this:

```
( ( ERDAT > '20210224' )
OR ( ERDAT = '20210224' AND ERFZEIT > '085956' )
OR ( AEDAT > '20210224' )
OR ( AEDAT = '20210224' AND AEZEIT > '231217' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM10', 'PM99' ) )
```

2: And there is an encore: - if the resulting split line is longer than 50 chars, I would like to split those lines at the last comma (,) before 50 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a negative lookahead assertion to exclude whitespace that is followed by another closing parenthesis from being replaced: `(?<=\))\s(?!\))`

Comment: That works, thanks! I'm still getting to grips with regex. Any ideas on how to split the results at last comma (,) before 50 chars each ttime, even if I have to process the split list separately?

Comment: Done! Yup - sometimes that string is longer than 50 chars and then I need it split at the comma (not inside a quoted string), as part of the final array of strings.

Comment: Concerning your encore: you might want to consider asking that as a separate question, as it doesn't really have anything to do with the original closing bracket problem. That way, both other people having a similar problem as well as people that can potentially help you with an answer have a better chance of finding it. But it should be possible with lookarounds as well. Link the new question in a comment and I'll have a look at it...

Comment: Maybe so, but would I was hoping that it may be possible inside the same regex. That it splits the regex according to this rule but then, at the same time (inside the same regex), split the resulting lines further at the last comma before 50 chars.

Comment: Your regex just matches the whitespace, not the text in between, which you want to process further.

Comment: I asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384830/regex-split-a-line-at-last-delimiter-inside-fixe-length

Comment: I did the same :) And also added the answer directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384922/regex-to-break-a-line-at-the-last-comma-only-if-it-is-longer-than-a-certain-numb/66384923#66384923

Comment: Thanks for that. I cannot comment there as I am still a noob around here. The example you did there only works if the line is more than 50 but less than a hundred. The lines I have to deal with could be thousands of characters long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229250/discussion-between-buddemat-and-chris-laurie).