# Regex to break a line at the last comma before a certain length / number of characters

Tags: c#, regex

Someone asked this as an encore to an otherwise unrelated question ([C# Regex split by multiple closing brackets sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383136/c-sharp-regex-split-by-multiple-closing-brackets-sets)), so I'm adding it as a separate question:

I have a number of lines and if one of those lines is longer than 50 chars, I would like to split those lines at the last comma (,) before 50 characters.

Example input:

```
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM10', 'PM99', 'PM59' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM01232132132', 'PM03' ) )
```

Expected output:

```
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM10',
 'PM99', 'PM59' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM01232132132',
 'PM03' ) )
```

Comment: Replace `(.{50},)` with `$1\r\n` [See it here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%7b50%7d%2c%29&i=AND+%28+AUART+IN+%28+%27PM01%27%2c+%27PM02%27%2c+%27PM03%27+%29+%29%0d%0aAND+%28+AUART+IN+%28+%27PM01%27%2c+%27PM02%27%2c+%27PM03%27%2c+%27PM10%27%2c+%27PM99%27%2c+%27PM59%27+%29+%29%0d%0aAND+%28+AUART+IN+%28+%27PM01%27%2c+%27PM01232132132%27%2c+%27PM03%27+%29+%29&r=%241%0d%0a)

Comment: That won't work. As your example shows, the resulting split will be longer than 50 characters. See expected output.

Comment: True. Sloppy of me ;) Change it to `^(?=.{50})(.{1,49},)`. [Here...](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3d.%7b50%7d%29%28.%7b1%2c49%7d%2c%29&i=AND+%28+AUART+IN+%28+%27PM01%27%2c+%27PM02%27%2c+%27PM03%27+%29+%29%0d%0aAND+%28+AUART+IN+%28+%27PM01%27%2c+%27PM02%27%2c+%27PM03%27%2c+%27PM10%27%2c+%27PM99%27%2c+%27PM59%27+%29+%29%0d%0aAND+%28+AUART+IN+%28+%27PM01%27%2c+%27PM01232132132%27%2c+%27PM03%27+%29+%29&r=%241%0d%0a&o=m). But that's *basically* what you already got as an answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also use a pattern without capture groups and a lookbehind asserting either the start of the string or a comma.

Then assert 50 chars to the right and match 1-49 characters followed by a comma.

In the replacement use the full match followed by a newline `$0\n`

```
(?<=^|,)(?=.{50}).{1,49},
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ObIjxn/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/csCY4e)

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>()
{
    "AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03' ) )",
    "AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM10', 'PM99', 'PM59' ) )",
    "AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM01232132132', 'PM03' ) )",
    "AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM0654654654654654654654654654651', 'PM02' ) )",
    "AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM04', 'PM11', 'PM12', 'PM13', 'PM14', 'PM15', 'PM16', 'PM21', 'PM22', 'PM23', 'PM24', 'PM25', 'PM31' ) )"
};
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=^|,)(?=.{50}).{1,49},");

foreach (String s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(s, "$0\n"));
}
```

Output

```
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM10',
 'PM99', 'PM59' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM01232132132',
 'PM03' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM0654654654654654654654654654651', 'PM02' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM04',
 'PM11', 'PM12', 'PM13', 'PM14', 'PM15', 'PM16',
 'PM21', 'PM22', 'PM23', 'PM24', 'PM25',
 'PM31' ) )
```

Comment: Great, this works better than mine since it gets the whole string in one replacement! Just for completeness sake, you could also use `\G` to assert the start of the string or the end of the previous match: `\G(?=.{50}).{1,49},`. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can start your regex with a positive lookahead assertion that matches the whole line if it is longer than 50 characters, then add a negative lookbehind that makes sure there are less than 50 characters before the comma you want to match:

`(?=.{50})(.*)(?<!.{50})(,)`

Then you have found the comma that you want to split at or e.g. replace with a comma and a newline.

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string pattern = @"(?=.{50})(.*)(?<!.{50})(,)";
      string replacement = "$1,\n";
      List<string> inputs = new List<string>();
      inputs.Add("AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03' ) )"); // shorter than 50 chars
      inputs.Add("AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM10', 'PM99', 'PM59' ) )");
      inputs.Add("AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM01232132132', 'PM03' ) )");
      inputs.Add("AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM0654654654654654654654654654651', 'PM02' ) )"); // first comma appearing later than character 50
     
      foreach (string input in inputs)
      {
          string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
          Console.WriteLine(result);
      }
   }
}
```

Note that this has some limitations:

1. if there is a comma within the quotes ('), the regex will **match**, which may or may not be what you want.
2. if the first comma appears later than at position 50, the regex will obviously **not match**
3. if the line is longer than ~100 characters, the second part will be again longer than 50 characters, which I guess is not what you want

The last point can be addressed by capturing the remainder in a capture group and using a recursion to apply the regex again should the remainder be longer than 50 characters:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      List<string> inputs = new List<string>();
      inputs.Add("AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03' ) )"); // shorter than 50 chars
      inputs.Add("AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM10', 'PM99', 'PM59' ) )");
      inputs.Add("AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM01232132132', 'PM03' ) )");
      inputs.Add("AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM0654654654654654654654654654651', 'PM02' ) )"); // first comma appearing later than character 50
      inputs.Add("AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM04', 'PM11', 'PM12', 'PM13', 'PM14', 'PM15', 'PM16', 'PM21', 'PM22', 'PM23', 'PM24', 'PM25', 'PM31' ) )"); // string longer than 100 chars, i.e. the remainder needs to be processed again
      List<string> results = new List<string>();
       
      var regex = new Regex(@"((?=.{50}).*(?<!.{50}),)(.*)");
    
      foreach (string input in inputs)
      {
          string str = input;
          while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) {
             var match = regex.Match(str);
             if (match.Success) {
                 results.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);         
                 str = match.Groups[2].Value;
             } else {
                 results.Add(str);
                 break;
             }
          }
      }
      Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", results));
   }
}
```

Result:

```
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM10',
 'PM99', 'PM59' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM01232132132',
 'PM03' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM0654654654654654654654654654651', 'PM02' ) )
AND ( AUART IN ( 'PM01', 'PM02', 'PM03', 'PM04',
 'PM11', 'PM12', 'PM13', 'PM14', 'PM15', 'PM16',
 'PM21', 'PM22', 'PM23', 'PM24', 'PM25',
 'PM31' ) )
```

To address the second point, you may consider breaking at commas `,` and whitespace `\s` instead of only commas (if that is possible in your application scenario). The regex for that would be `((?=.{50}).*(?<!.{50})[\s,])(.*)`.